# Bat script faz perder permissões

Tags: windows, script, cmd

Eu tenho uma pasta no meu servidor e é aberta a todos e com todas as permissões (Escrever, Ler, executar...).

Percebi que quando executo o meu script bat, deixo de conseguir fazer qualquer tipo de ação nesta pasta, mesmo tendo as permissões.

Já aconteceu em 3 contas diferentes da minha rede.

O script é o seguinte:

```
@echo 

C:\Users\it.suporte\Desktop\windowskeyfinder > SSSsss.txt
pause

mkdir %computername%
pause

move %computername% > M:\INFORMATICA\stock
pause

msinfo32 /report MS%computername%.txt

wmic product get name, version > S%computername%.txt

move %computername% M:\INFORMATICA\stock\%computername%

move S%computername%.txt M:\INFORMATICA\stock\%computername%

move MS%computername%.txt M:\INFORMATICA\stock\%computername%
```

Answer (score 1):

Ele não faz perder as permissões, o que ocorre é algum erro antes das ações que escrevem na pasta, ai o seu bat é fechado/abortado sem usar a pasta apontada.

**1.** Como diz um amigo, *"tenha paz interior e use aspas nos seus comandos"*

**2.** Evite criar uma pasta em lugar "temporário" se depois move-lá para um destino permanente (já definido), crie direto lá onde vai ficar.

**3.** O mesmo que o item 2. se aplica aos arquivos, crie seus logs direto la

**4.** Observe e considere: *Já aconteceu em 3 contas diferentes da minha rede.*

- a) Qual o Nome do Computador, tem algum carácter especial no nome?
  '%computername%
- b) Existe esse caminho e o arquivo apontado?
  `"C:\Users\it.suporte\Desktop\windowskeyfinder"`?

```
@echo off 

wmic path softwareLicensingService get OA3xOriginalProductKey|find "-" >"%~dp0SSSsss.txt"
mkdir "M:\INFORMATICA\stock\%computername%\."
msinfo32 /report >"M:\INFORMATICA\stock\%computername%\MS%computername%.txt"
wmic product get name, version >"M:\INFORMATICA\stock\%computername%\S%computername%.txt"
```